# output of watch several commands not clear

Tags: whitespace, watch

I am restoring a database backup on my server and i need to watch output of `df -h` and restore utility `db2pd -utilities`. I tried this:
`watch -n 2 "db2pd -utilities && df -h`
output(summarized):

```
    Every 2.0s: db2pd -utilities && df -h    

  Database Member 0 -- Active -- Up 0 days 23:11:19 

  Utilities:
  Address        ID         Type        State      Invoker    Priority   

  0x000000E0     1          RESTORE      0          0          0          


  Progress:
  Address            ID         PhaseNum   CompletedWork                
  0x00003088         1          1          1073745920 bytes                          
  Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 /dev/sda3              39G  824M   36G   3% /
 tmpfs                 253G   16K  253G   1% /dev/shm
 /dev/sda2             194M   36M  149M  20% /boot
 /dev/sda1             200M  264K  200M   1% /boot/efi
 /dev/sda4              20G  215M   19G   2% /home
 /dev/sda5              20G  1.4G   17G   8% /opt
 /dev/sda9             166G  6.6G  151G   5% /tempWork
 /dev/sda7             9.7G  152M  9.0G   2% /tmp
 /dev/sda6              20G  227M   19G   2% /var
```

actually the outputs are more and long I had to remove some parts and they combine together and become hard to read. what should i use to make space between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that's necessary is to add a printf statement between the original commands: 
`watch -n 2 "db2pd -utilities && printf '\n\n\n' && df -h"` You can use `grep -v` to hide any extraneous data from the individual utilities.